# Images downloaded as .part file

Tags: javascript, image, png, base64

i want to allow user to download some png image in my HTML page.

i searched and i found this :

`window.location.href = img.src.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');`

it's works fine (open a dialog to save the image file ).

but the problem that the file name looks like : `<random letters>.part`.

so how to solve this ?

and can i change my own file name ?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

i want it in the browser side not server side (using java script).

Comment: What MIME type are you sending with the .part file?

Comment: this : data:image/png;base64,

Comment: You can't name a file that is specified via data URI. See RFC 2397.

Comment: this photo is generated by canvas.getDataURL("image/png").
is that make sense ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the content disposition in your headers to force the download have a filename.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.png"');
```

Comment: sorry, but is this php or js ? i want js